# Check if array is of scalar types

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I want my template class to not allow arrays with not scalar types as template parameters, for this i have written these auxiliary types:

```
template<bool> struct AssertTrue;

template<> struct AssertTrue<true> {};

template < class T>
struct FilterOutArraysWithNonScalarTypes
{
    typedef std::true_type Allowed;
};

template < class T, size_t N>
struct FilterOutArraysWithNonScalarTypes<T[N]>
{
    typedef std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_scalar<T>::value> Allowed;
};
```

and then in constructor of my object i check this way

```
CheckAllowance<FilterOutArraysWithNonScalarTypes<T>::Allowed::value>;
```

Can i do it nicer?

EDIT:

Sorry, i misprinted AssertTrue with CheckAllowance .

Comment: Try using the Boost MPL library.  It has a bunch of predefined classes and templates for this.

Comment: @randomusername i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AssertTrue` isn't used in the code you've shown.  I suppose you can replace it with `static_assert()`.  Otherwise everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(!(std::is_array<T>::value && 
                    !std::is_scalar<std::remove_extent_t<T>>::value),
                  "Must not be a non-scalar array");
};
```

If you feel like this is too verbose, you could make an alias template trait:

```
template <typename T>
using is_non_scalar_array = std::integral_constant<
                              bool,
                              std::is_array<T>::value && 
                              !std::is_scalar<std::remove_extent_t<T>>::value
                            >;
```

Or as a variable template:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_non_scalar_array = std::is_array<T>::value && 
                                     !std::is_scalar<std::remove_extent_t<T>>::value;
```